# AWS Lambda without any parameters

Tags: java, aws-lambda

[image]Is there any way to create a Java Lambda function without any parameters?

My Lambda job is to be scheduled, no S3 events or any at all.
Would I still have to implement an interface? Which one?
They all seem to require input parameters.

If I try without any parameters Eclipse IDE is giving me errors.

Even with the specified jars in the classpath, If I try the following:

```
public String handleRequest() {

DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(-1, -1);

List<HubspotContact> contacts = MySoapClient.getRegistrants(datePicker.getStartDate(),datePicker.getEndDate());

insertToDB(contacts);



return null;
}
```

I get this Test error:

> "errorMessage": "javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException", "errorType":
>   "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",

This is what I use for handler info:

> client.CDSSync::handleRequest

If I change the handler info to:

> client.CDSSync

I get the following error:

> Class does not implement an appropriate handler interface:
>   client.CDSSync

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking here. Are you confusing _Java lambda expressions_ with _AWS Lambda functions_?

Comment: Are you trying to *invoke* a lambda function from java code?

Comment: `() -> { doSomething(); }` should work. This is a lambda without any parameters passed to it.

Comment: @christopher yes, I am using AWS Lambda with Java. I updated my post.

Comment: @MichaelClayton I'm guessing this is Java 8, correct?  Can you post more information - what dependencies do you have in your `pom.xml`?  Do you have a small example that shows the problem?  `DataPicker` is, I believe, a JavaFX class - you can't use a UI in AWS Lambda so what are you trying to do there?

Comment: @stdunbar I updated my post with a pic of the pom.xml. the DatePicker is a custom class I created, it's just a convenience for me to get a start and end date, not JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just ignore the inputs.  Something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;

public class S3EventLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
       // do your thing
    }
```

Comment: Now I'm just getting the "javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException error. I updated my post to include a screen shot to show what jars I have. I can't seem to get past the ServiceException.